# Data Splitting in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, split

I am looking for a gem that will split a CSV dataset into smaller datasets for training and test on a machine learning system.  There is a package in **R** which will do this, based on random sampling; but my research has not turned up anything in Ruby.  The reason I wanted to do this in Ruby is that the original dataset is quite large, e.g. 17 million rows or 5.5 gig.  **R** expects to load the entire dataset into memory.  Ruby is far more flexible.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the smarter_csv Ruby gem and set the chunk_size to the desired sample size, 
and then save the chunks as Resque jobs , which can then be processed in parallel.

https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv

see examples on that GitHub page.

Answer (score 1):

This will partition your original data to two files without loading it all into memory:

```
require 'csv'

sample_perc = 0.75

CSV.open('sample.csv','w') do |sample_out|
  CSV.open('test.csv','w') do |test_out|
    CSV.foreach('alldata.csv') do |row|
      (Random.rand < sample_perc ? sample_out : test_out) << row
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a really elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is built-in to ruby, you don't need any gem to do this:

```
require 'csv'

csvs = (1..10).map{|i| CSV.open("data#{i}.csv", "w")}
CSV.foreach("data.csv") do |row|
  csvs.sample << row
end
```

CSV.foreach will not load the entire file into memory.

Comment: Hmm.  I guess my question then is how do you set the sample size.  Eg. Training .75 of the main file and Testing .25 of the main file.  The other issue concerns the possibility of overlap.  You can't have any given row in both the training and testing subsets.  I do appreciate the response.

Comment: @pguardiario Can you join here - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27184/ruby-conceptual?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what those numbers mean or what you mean by testing or training.

Comment: When you are trying to build a predictive model for a given dataset, you first break up the dataset into two groups, a training set and a test set.  You use the training set to build a predictive model, eg a regression model, classification tree or bayesian network.  You then test the predictive model on the test set.  You want to assign a record to either the training set or test set on a random basis and you want to make sure that the a record does not appear in both sets.  As to the numbers, they reflect the % of the records in the training set (75%) and test set (25%).

Comment: Ok, well my answer describes splitting a csv into 10 smaller csv's. Dbenhur's answer might be closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to write your own code for this, based around Ruby's bundled `csv` gem. There are lots of possibilities for how to split the data, and the requirement to do this efficiently over such a large data set is quite specialist, whilst also not requiring that much code.

However, you might have some luck looking through the many sub-features of `ai4r`

I've not yet found many mature pre-packaged machine learning algorithms for Ruby (that you might also find in R or in Python's `scikitlearn`). No random forests, gbm etc - or if there are, they are difficult to find. There *is* a Ruby interface to R. Also wrappers for ATLAS. I have tried neither.

I do make use of `ruby-fann` (neural nets) , and the gem `narray` is your friend for large numerical data sets.

Comment: Thanks for the response Neil.  I did alot of digging and I could not find anything.  It doesn't seem that ML has really made its way to the Ruby scene.  The problem with R is that it has not quite made it's way to OOP and file handling is a nightmare.  I have been using Ruby to Mudge the data.  Since I am writing the code anyway, I might as well try my hand at producing a gem.  I just did not want to reinvent the wheel.